# AIML pattern matching - howto?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, pattern-matching, neural-network, aiml

I'm having a problem trying to understand how does AIML pattern matching works. 
What's the difference between `_` and `*`? And how I should use them to get the best match?

I have [this document](http://www.alicebot.org/documentation/matching.html) only,  but it lacks some good examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A * will match anything unless a pattern of a word or several words are matched

A _ will match anything even if a pattern of a word or several words could match

`<pattern>BYE _</pattern>` does not make sense since `<pattern>BYE *</pattern>` matches the same patterns but `<pattern>BYE _</pattern>` will shadow `<pattern>BYE * SEE YOU</pattern>` whereas BYE * won't.

Use _ carefully, for example _ would match anything and your bot will give the same answer every times.

`<pattern>_ A COUPLE OF WORDS *</pattern>` and `<pattern>_ A COUPLE OF WORDS</pattern>` is the proper way to use _ if you want to catch every times A COUPLE OF WORDS is inside or at the end of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

_ and * are both wildcards, the difference is where they should be used in pattern matching.

```
_ should be used before the word or phrase you're matching on
* should be used after the word or phrase you're matching on.
```

See: [AIML spec](http://www.alicebot.org/TR/2001/WD-aiml/)

To understand this better it may be worth looking at examples in the existing AIML bots.

See: [Downloads](http://www.alicebot.org/downloads/), this one [Saluations.aiml](http://www.alicebot.org/aiml/aaa/Salutations.aiml) has examples

Comment: So that would mean that 'HELLO _' is an invalid expression? Right?

Comment: This is what I have found in 
http://www.alicebot.org/aiml/aaa/Salutations.aiml

What's the essential difference between these two patterns?

<category>
    <pattern>* BYE</pattern>
    <template>
        OK see you later <get name="name"/>.
    </template>
</category>      

<category>
    <pattern>_ BYE</pattern>
    <template>
        See you later. <sr/>
    </template>
</category>

Btw, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: I would say, based on the spec that HELLO _ is invalid yes.
And that was a seriously bad example on my part. I don't think the * BYE  would ever be evaluated.
* BYE is in my view invalid, and should be BYE *.